# Choosing from a list of strings in zsh?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

I am adding 3 lines to pick a zsh theme from a list of the themes that I like.  This is what I have come up with, but of course, it doesn't work.  I think it is because I am declaring an array and it wants me to have numbers in the array instead of strings.  I also am probably confusing bash and zsh.

```
declare -a themes=("random" "half-life" "wezm" "sonicradish" "muse" "adben" "wedisagree" "ys" "dst" "tonotdo" "re5et" "jtrilley");  #list of 12 favorite themes
r=$((RANDOM%12));  #Pick random number 1:12
ZSH_THEME=${themes[$r]}; #Set the ZSH_THEME to the random choice
```

Comment: 1. from where does $RANDOM is initialized ?

Comment: 2. [r] should be [$r]

Comment: 1 - is RANDOM not a builtin function?

Comment: 2 - good point. fixed this and still giving the "expects number" answer

Comment: echo $((RANDOM%12)) returns a result

Comment: after the last change what is the value in `${ZSH_THEME}` ? is it populated correctly/as expected ?

Comment: i separated the `declare -a theme` and the assignment `theme=(list_contents)` and works now...(echo ${ZSH_THEME} is correct)  but also prints out these error messages

Comment: `~/.zshrc:1: command not found: B0`      
`~/.zshrc:1: command not found: 95`       
`~/.zshrc:1: command not found: c#`

Comment: But that has nothing to do with my original question thank you so much nabeel

Comment: happy to hear it's working for you :)